# How can I exchange type of 'Result<Data>' to Data type in Swift

Tags: swift

I got Some ERROR, but I have no idea.

[image]

The code is here.

```
   func object(for key: String) -> Observable<SwiftyJSON.JSON?> {
        return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in

            self?.cache?.async.object(forKey: key) { result in
                guard let data = result else {
                    observer.onNext(nil)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                    return
                }
                Async.userInteractive {
                    var json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(data: data)

                    Async.main {
                        if let error = json.error {
                            observer.onError(error)
                        } else {
                            observer.onNext(json)
                        }
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    }
                }
            }

            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

I used this https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache.

How can I exchange 'Result' to 'Data'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Result` is an enum that holds either the (successful) value, or the error.

So, like any enum, you can use a `switch` statement, or a `if case let` notation.

```
if case let .success(data) = result {
   // do something with data
}
```

```
// or similarly
guard case let .success(data) = result else { return }
// do something with data
```

Or:

```
switch result {
case .success(let data):
   // do something with data
   ...
case .failure(let error):
   // do something with error
```

You can also `try` to get the value out of `Result`, which would `throw` in case of an error:

```
let data = try result.get()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I got solved.
I used this 'guard case let .value(data) = result else { return }'